# Joomla 3.6 File upload file to article

Tags: plugin, com-plugins

i am using the technique to add custom fields to articles described here:
https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_core_components_using_a_plugin

Everything is working well, except for file-uploads.
My first guess was to use the media-field type to let the user upload pdf files, but it only supports image files, so, i thought about using the file-field type.
But it does not upload anything, just returns the filename.
I checked and saw, that the form is missing enctype="multipart/form-data", so i took a look at:
administrator/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/edit.php
and noticed that the form-tag is hard-coded, no possibility to add the enctype:

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_content&layout=' . $layout . $tmpl . '&id=' . (int) $this->item->id); ?>" method="post" name="adminForm" id="item-form" class="form-validate">
```

My question:
Is there any possibility to let the user upload pdf or doc files in a single article without core-hacks?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Solved it this way:

Installed the newest JCE-Release and used a media-field instead of a file-field.
JCE replaces the media field with its own filepicker, wich is limited to images only.
In the form-field xml i've added:

```
filter=""
```

That did the trick, now i am able to select pdf files with a Joomla media field in a content-plugin.